# How would one properly unwrap/texture this shape?

Tags: texturing, uv, sculpting, uv-image-editor

Specifically the moss on top. Currently, the texture is simply projected from view (which in my case is the camera view). Unfortunately, that's cheating and would prevent me from saving this asset for future use due to the ugly/skewed back faces.

None of the auto unwrap options even remotely do the job right and I simply can't imagine where I could place seams to manually unwrap without chopping it up.

I'm sure that my little land bridge is the culprit throwing the projections off, but I'd rather learn to fix it, instead of deleting it.

Any suggestions are appreciated, Thank You[image][image][image]

Comment: what do you mean by "where I could place seams to manually unwrap without chopping it up"? A solution could be to use Smart UV Project and then to paint on the object for example with the Stencil method?

Comment: By that I mean that with simpler hard surface modeling, it's usually relatively simple to mark seams and unwrap an object to manually lay it down on a texture. Whereas with this shape, it's almost a paradox figuring out where to cut with seams to try and unwrap. And as I mentioned, all one-click unwrap options from the drop down menu just absolutely mangle the texture. I'm not familiar with the "Stencil Method"?

Comment: by stencil method I mean you unwrap with Smart UV Project mode, give your object a black image in the Image Texture node, switch to Texture Paint mode, select the Draw brush, in the N panel > Tool > open Texture and load your grass texture, then Mapping > Stencil, see for example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lO8qDNZf5o0  ... and if you want to limit the painting to only the selected faces, enable the Paint Mask once in Texture Paint mode

Comment: I'll definitely be looking into it, thanks for your time. Will report back with results!

Comment: or you can simply select the faces you want (in Edit mode / Face, with C enabled), unwrap, Ctrl i to invert selection, unwrap again, then place the UVs as you want in UV Editor?